# Error: Could not load model total/sub_total!

Tags: php, opencart, themes

Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Установил `OpenCart 2.3.0.2`. Поставил тему [`[Pav Flower]`](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=26285)

Но при заходе на сайт пишет такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Could not load model total/sub_total!' in /var/www/site/system/engine/loader.php:59 
    Stack trace: 
    #0 /var/www/site/catalog/controller/common/cart.php(39): Loader->model('total/sub_total') 
    #1 [internal function]: ControllerCommonCart->index(Array) 
    #2 /var/www/site/system/engine/action.php(51): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
    #3 /var/www/site/system/engine/loader.php(24): Action->execute(Object(Registry), Array) 
    #4 /var/www/site/catalog/controller/common/header.php(149): Loader->controller('common/cart') 
    #5 [internal function]: ControllerCommonHeader->index(Array) 
    #6 /var/www/site/system/engine/action.php(51): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
    #7 /var/www/site/system/engine/loader.php(24): Action->execute(Object(Regi in /var/www/site/system/engine/loader.php on line 59
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Как написано на странице описания темы,

```
Compatibility 2.0.0.0, 2.0.1.0, 2.0.1.1, 2.0.2.0, 2.0.3.1, 2.1.0.1, 2.1.0.2, 2.2.0.0
```

т.е. для ветки 2.3 она работать не будет